# How do I draw a straight line parallel to a square side?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I want to draw a straight line leaving the down left tip of my square D.

My code is the following

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
        \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
        \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,scale=3,dashed,draw](D) {$D$};
        \node[draw, right of=D,yshift=1cm, node distance=6cm](G){G};
        \node[right of=D, yshift=1cm, node distance =3.5cm] (ygets) {$y \gets U_{2n}$};
        \node[right of=D, yshift=-1.22cm, node distance=2.5cm](vazio){};
        \node[above of=G, node distance=1cm] (k) {$k \gets U_n$};


        \path[draw,->] (G.south) |- (D.east);
        \path[draw,->] (k.south) -- (G.north);
        \path[draw,->] (ygets.south) |- node[near end, above]{$y$} (D.east);
        \path[draw,->] (D.south east) -- node[above] {b} (vazio);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The resulting figure is

[image: Arrow with letter b should be straight]

Any tips or tricks on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two ways:

```
\draw[->] (D.south east) -- ++(2,0) node[above,midway] {b};
```

This one starts from `D.south east` and proceeds horizontally for `2` (or any number you want, it also takes measures, like `1cm`) and `0` vertically, so it goes to the right.  Then you have

```
\draw[->] (D.south east) -- (D.south east-|k);
```

This one starts at the same point and continues until it reaches the node `k`, but still going horizontally, and there it stops. Which solution you decide to adopt depends on the needs of the case. By the way, writing `\draw` instead of `\path[draw]` is easier, and the first command is actually the short version of the second one.

Answer (score 3):

There are other ways as well:

Instead of your existing definition of `vazio`, define it as

```
\coordinate[right=1.5cm of D.south east] (vazio);
```

The syntax `right=<len> of ...` requires the `positioning` library, so you have to add `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` to the preamble. Note that `right=of` is recommended over `right of=`, see [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)

A slightly more complicated approach, which would also work if `D` was rotated, is to load the `calc` library, and say

```
\draw[->] (D.south east) -- node[above] {b} ($(D.south west)!1.6!(D.south east)$);
```

The value `1.6` can be adjusted to what is useful. The coordinate `($(D.south west)!1.6!(D.south east)$)` is the point on the line between the two bottom corners of `D` that is 1.6 times the distance between them, away from `D.south west`.

Output and complete code below. Both alternatives are added here, hence two arrows in the image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
        \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
        \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,scale=3,dashed,draw](D) {$D$};
        \node[draw, right of=D,yshift=1cm, node distance=6cm](G){G};
        \node[right of=D, yshift=1cm, node distance =3.5cm] (ygets) {$y \gets U_{2n}$};
        % option 1
        \coordinate[right=1.5cm of D.south east] (vazio);

        \node[above of=G, node distance=1cm] (k) {$k \gets U_n$};


        \draw[->] (G.south) |- (D.east);
        \draw[->] (k.south) -- (G.north);
        \draw[->] (ygets.south) |- node[near end, above]{$y$} (D.east);
        \draw[->] (D.south east) -- node[above] {b1} (vazio);

        % option 2
        \draw[->] (D.south east) -- node[below] {b2} ($(D.south west)!1.6!(D.south east)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can see the utility of the second method, but the first method is unnecessarily long. I mean you could do the same using the first method I suggested doing `\draw[->] (D.south east) -- ++(1.5cm,0) coordinate (vazio);`, right? I can't think of any case where defining a coordinate separately, for the sole purpose of drawing a path, would be preferable.

Comment: @Alenanno The first method was merely an improved version of what the OP had tried already (`\node[right of=D, yshift=-1.22cm, node distance=2.5cm](vazio){};`, and drawing the line to `vazio`).

Comment: Yes, I understand. I was just wondering if maybe I had missed something about it. :P